# for a record type know pagelayout on case object

Tags: case, page-layout, record-type

In my org many record Types and page layout present. case Managment support record type have assigned a page layout how i can know that which pagelayout is assigned for c**ase Managment support record type**.

Comment: You mean, like in Apex Code, the API, or just using the UI?

Comment: just using the UI..... I'm creating a new record type but requirement is pick already created page layout.

Comment: You can see the current assignments in Setup > Customize > Cases > Page Layouts > View Page Layout Assignments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can easily visualize and manage page layouts assignments by record types and profiles. go to **customize > case > record Types >** then click on the page layout assignment button
[image]

From this matrix you can view and change your assignments as you like:

[image]